# iOS - settings page how to remove just notifications

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a IOS settings screen (on ios 8.0) which gets generated using this code:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert) 
        categories:nil]];



[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

the result looked like this it seems:

[image]

My goal is to remove just the notifications area but i'd like to let the privacy and 'use cellular data' remain.

On the simulator there is no privacy and 'use Cellular Data' appearing.  Is this whole issue because im on a simulator ?

Comment: That is not possible, if you register for notification that section will always be shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use "registerForRemoteNotifications" this settings will be there automatically and can't be omitted. You are not allowed to disable user notifications settings if you want to use notifications.

Comment: hey the 'use cellular data' settings. is that specifically for my app, or the entire phone ?

Comment: just your app – the user can disable using cellular for your app :)

Answer (score 1):

This could be out of date, but according to [Technote 2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42):

> **Resetting the Push Notifications Permissions Alert on iOS**
>
> The first time a push-enabled app registers for push notifications, iOS asks the user if they wish to receive notifications for that app. Once the user has responded to this alert it is not presented again unless the device is restored or the app has been uninstalled for at least a day.
>
> If you want to simulate a first-time run of your app, you can leave the app uninstalled for a day. You can achieve the latter without actually waiting a day by following these steps:
>
> 1. Delete your app from the device.
> 2. Turn the device off completely and turn it back on.
> 3. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and set the date ahead a day or more.
> 4. Turn the device off completely again and turn it back on.